# Does Django v1.8 support `register_view` method of django-adminplus v0.3?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a function to register a custom view using 'register_view' method of django-adminplus(v.0.3) with django 1.6.5 that works fine with the view. Now I wish to migrate the code to django 1.8 since the former is no longer supported. But django 1.8 doesn't seem to support the above function call of django-adminplus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to django-adminplus 0.4. If you look at the [commit history](https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus/commits/master), it looks like support for Django 1.7 and 1.8 was added after 0.3, which you are currently running.

The [readme](https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus#installing-adminplus) also explains that you need to use the `SimpleAdminConfig` with Django 1.7+, to prevent auto discovery.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig',  # instead of 'django.contrib.admin'
    # ...
)
```